# Java insert into sql with current date

Tags: sql

I have a table called `order` with `userID, itemID , dateOfOrder`

How do I insert a row with today's date?

I've tried for example:

```
INSERT INTO lending 
VALUES(111, 1, SELECT CURDATE())
```

but it doesn't work. any idea what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Maybe `getdate()`?  What database?

Comment: SELECT CURDATE() works fine and it returns the correct date. my problem is with the syntax within the insert.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  The `SELECT` is superfluous in this case.  SQL statements aren't structured that way, you just call the function to get the value you need.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

```
INSERT INTO lending VALUES(111, 1, CURDATE())
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO lending VALUES(111, 1, **SELECT** CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems) you are using, so here are two of the main ones: If you are using MySql look at the [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) method. If you are using Oracle check out [`SYSDATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm). For anything else, e.g. MS SQL, some quick googling should find you an answer.

Comment: Or simply use the standard `CURRENT_DATE` function. That works in nearly all DBMS.

Comment: I've always used `NOW`, `SYSDATE`, etc. because I always seem to need the time as well.

Comment: The (ANSI) standard function would be `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good to know. And looking at the docs, `NOW` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` are actually the same thing in MySQL - checks out in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/5963). `SYSDATE` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` [turn out different](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/6043) in Oracle, but the timestamp can take a format mask according to the docs so it can probably work out in the end.  Learned some new stuff, thanks =)

Comment: NOW() isn't good for me as it returns the date and hour... i need just the date. anyhow the problem has been solved.. see my reply above :)